# DISTINCT, SKIP and LIMIT in Cypher Query

Tags: neo4j, cypher

```
MATCH (n)
RETURN DISTINCT n
ORDER BY n.name
SKIP 5
LIMIT 10
```

When I write such a query, it will not always return 10 results because first the limitation is done and then DISTINCT command filters the results; so the DISTINCT command works on 10 results. How can I change this query to return DISTINCT results and then limits them to 10? I'd like to get 10 results every time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Does this do what you want?

```
MATCH (n)
WITH DISTINCT n
    ORDER BY n.name
RETURN n
    SKIP 5
    LIMIT 10
```